# Orders list based on time period

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by, orders

I have one table "orderdetails" table, I want Orders list from 06-01-2015 to 06-30- 15 per day below 60 orders based on time period like 00-01 and 01-02 like that

```
select
  convert(datetime, Convert(varchar(50), OrderDate, 101)) as dateorder,
  count(orderid) as ordercount   
from
  orderdetails 
where
  OrderDate between convert(datetime,Convert(varchar(50),'6/01/2015',101)) and convert(datetime,Convert(varchar(50),'06/30/2015',101))   
  and transactionid is not null 
  and DATEPART(HOUR,OrderDate) between '1' and '2'   
group by
  convert(datetime, Convert(varchar(50), OrderDate, 101))  
having
  count(orderid) < 60
```

But this query showing wrong list... its not displaying in count(orderid) < 60 orders its displaying overall orders, not below per day orders 60...

Comment: Show your desire output in tabular form."on time period like 00-01 and 01-02 like that".this is not clear.Also why in order table transactionid will be null.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
select
 convert(datetime, Convert(varchar(50), OrderDate, 101)) as dateorder,
 count(orderid) as ordercount   
 from
 orderdetails 
 where
 OrderDate between convert(datetime,Convert(varchar(50),'6/01/2015',101)) and convert(datetime,Convert(varchar(50),'06/30/2015',101))   
and transactionid is not null 
and DATEPART(HOUR,OrderDate) between '1' and '2'   
group by
 convert(datetime, Convert(varchar(50), OrderDate, 101)) ) t

where ordercount   < 60
```